# Blogger Integration with Flash possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, drupal-7, blogger

i need help that can blogger be integrated into flash/AS3.0??
I have been searching and found that Drupal (v7) has this feature coupled with its Services Module, i tried and load drupal posts into flash using AMFSERVER ( another module ) , but i was unable to parse or get meaning from the loaded data.
Anyhow i was just testing , as my blog is on blogger.com , i dont wish to move it to anywhere else as it suits my needs, but i want to have a front page with my blog post loaded into SWF.
Can it be possible with blogger same functionality as given by drupal?
I am not talking about fetching RSS links, but fetching lists of posts and when selected, load data associated with single post..

Comment: So are you trying to load your Blogger web pages into a flash swf? What advantage or constraint do you have that makes you want to load it in a swf vs a normal HTML based browser?

Comment: i have my site and aliased blogger ,they are seprate domains and the idea is to pull the blogger posts into my site, taking advantage of cms

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you should be able to use the protocol blogger API to pull in the system xml. It's a lot of development work, but the idea is possible. See the below documentation on use the raw url protocol API:

http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

Edit, there's also this Flash library to look into:
http://code.google.com/p/as3bloggerlib/

Comment: the Project page http://code.google.com/p/as3bloggerlib/ says that flash api is only for AIR , is there any for FLEX ( i prefer AS3.0 using FlashDevelop)

Comment: i go to API Access page and reqquest for blogger services, but it didnt give me api key immediately, but i get one for Google+ , is blooger api (key) is still available?